# Select a range of cells that I only know: the starting cell, the size of one of the columns and the number of columns?

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I have the following incomplete table:

[image]

That I need to select the range highlighted.

I can't use the following code because the table is incomplete:

```
Range("C8").Select 'C8 is the first value of "Item" column, the only column that need to be fully filled
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
```

So, I'm trying to select the last filled cell of "Item" column and offset it to "Custo Unitario" column. Then, I need to select till "Data" column, so I'm coding something like:

```
Range("C8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, -6)).Select`
```

But it isn't working. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: `Range("C8").End(xlDown).Offset(,-1).Resize(,6).Select`, but see [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(Range("C8").Offset(0, -1), Range("C8").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 4)).Select
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).